# How to ensure in Rails that Resque queues works each on in a different job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, resque, worker

I've seen some documentation about resque, and all the tips tell to run the queues with this command:

`rake resque:work QUEUE='*'`

What is this command really doing? Is it running all the queues in just one job?

I didn't find documentation talking about how to run the queues one by one. But, is there any performance difference considering that I will run all of them in the same server?

Comment: Queue refers to the number of workers.

Comment: Yes, but is it creating a job for each worker?

Comment: @MKumar, `QUEUE='*'` means you're spawning this worker to take any queues in which jobs will appear. I believe you're thinking of `COUNT=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next command

```
rake resque:work QUEUE='*'
```

creates a **single process** that includes all your queues, so definitely, it won't have a good performance. If you have multiples queues, it will work as if they were sequential.

If you want to have each queue running in a different process, you should execute your queues one by one:

```
rake resque:work QUEUE=queue_one &
rake resque:work QUEUE=queue_two &
rake resque:work QUEUE=queue_three &
```